# After successful login django giving 404 error

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a login page, and after user logs in it should take him to the main page under articles.

I have the main project called pnb, then i have 2 other apps, which are users and articles

Under the pnb -> urls.py i have the following

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('signin', views.signin, name='signin'),
    path('signout', views.signout, name='signout'),
    path('articles', include('articles.urls')),
]
```

Under users -> urls.py i have the following

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home

urlpatterns = [
 path('', home, name = "home"),
]
```

Under users -> views.py i have the following

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import articles.views

def home(request):
    return render(request, "users/home.html")

def signin(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('articles/index.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Bad Credentials")
            return redirect('home')

def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

Under articles -> urls.py i have the following

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.articles_view, name='articles_view'),
]
```

Under articles -> views.py i have the following

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Article
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def articles_view(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'index.html',{
        'articles': articles
    })
```

The issue i am having is that everytime i log in successfully, i keep getting the following error and can't figure out why, because the files exist there and not sure why i keep getting a 404 error on this

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/index.html
Using the URLconf defined in pnb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
signin [name='signin']
signout [name='signout']
articles [name='articles_view']
The current path, articles/index.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: i think that one of names that you shouldn't name your app with is "users" because it will conflict with an existing packages

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing  http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/index.html which is not defined anywhere in your url conf.
Instead you should redirect to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles to view the desired page. So change as directed below:

```
return redirect('articles/index.html') #from this

if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('articles') #to this
```

Your view should also look like for Django to pick the template:

```
def articles_view(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'articles/index.html',{
        'articles': articles
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much @nick, i think i am getting close, no for some reason i am getting this error

Comment: thanks nick now i am getting template not found error for index.html, even though its in there under articles -> templates -> articles -> index.html

Comment: You need to do articles/index.html. One way to fix this issue is to create a project level templates directory then edit your settings.py to be aware of the global templates directory in your project.

Comment: I think that worked, but now i am getting this error   Reverse for 'articles' not found. 'articles' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: The name of the url you have above is "articles_view" so you can change it to just "articles"